# Difference between Oauth2 v1.0 and v2.0

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

What's the difference between this? Microsoft have a /oauth2/ or a /ouath2/v2.0/ call point and I'm not sure what the difference is? They're both oAuth 2.0 and current right?

Answer (score 1):

It is like API versioning. When they realized they needed to alter some things, this technique helped iterate faster and identify these modifications. Change in an API is inevitable as your knowledge and experience of a system improve. So, that is like here with OAuth2.0 because it is just an API as well. Managing the impact of this change can be quite a challenge when it threatens to break existing client integration. As a result, they created something new and better. Last but not least public-facing APIs, or where all clients are not under your direct control, can better serve the evolving needs of the business by having some form of version control in place. So that's it. These two are not different but helped Microsoft to make modifications and improve their current system (API) for all of its client applications, and yes they are both OAuth2.0 and current.

Comment: Thanks for this info and clarifying! I get it now, wish I had an extra point so you could get my vote aha

Comment: Whenever, you get reputation, then please UPVOTE and ACCEPT my answer.